# how to update TTL for row

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I know that to update TTL a column value needs to be read and re-inserted with new TTL

What is best way to minimize performance impact of this ? if I have a CF with million rows and want to set ttl of 1hr for all rows, then reading and writing back all rows is very expensive

Even if i do this, is there any effect on other simultaneous queries ? will teh result of other queries will be doifferent when I am in middle of updating TTL ?

Can i use any other approch writing a script that will deleting the rows after 1hr ? what will be implications of this approach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cassandra ttl on a row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544051/cassandra-ttl-on-a-row)